# How to stop "save your password" key icon to appear in search bar?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I am working on to disable browser to prompt save password pop-up. I have successfully done that by taking the input fields out of form and using hidden input fields in actual form. It stopped browser to prompt save password pop-up in chrome as well as mozilla. In chrome browser when I type password in input field a key icon appears in search bar on right side. When I click on that it asks to save password. How can I hide that icon too. I am using angularjs.

Comment: Why do you want to? Let users user their browser however they want, including using strong passwords and storing them in a password manager, as recommended by many security experts.

Comment: @IMSoP, our security auditor has recommend to suppress that because its a B2B project.

Comment: Sigh, I should have known an out of touch security "expert" would be the one behind this. If they're so smart, maybe they can tell you how to suppress it.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. 
See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg, you can go to any login page in chrome, type in the password field and the key icon will appear in right corner in search bar.